# Trouble with network thread and swing thread

Tags: java, multithreading, forms, swing, sockets

I have an java application using Socket TCP/IP and GUI. Server always listens connection and receives message from client. When server received message, it will show a swing form.
My trouble is when I click on close button, the application will stop although I set server socket ALWAYS listens connection (by put method `serverSocket.accept()` in loop `while(true)`).
How can I solve that problem ?

Here is my code on Server:
public class TCPServer {

```
ServerSocket server = null;
BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;
Socket client = null;

//open serverSocket
public void openServer() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(1234);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//accept connection and read data
public void listening() {
    try {

        while (true) {
            client = server.accept();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            //read data from stream
            String s = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("String receive:  " + s);

            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void closeServer() {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }

        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
        if (server != null) {
            server.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    TCPServer server = new TCPServer();
    server.openServer();
    server.listening();
    server.closeServer();
}
```

}

Comment: show the code that handles the close event

Comment: Can you show us the NewJFrame code? Are you sure you are not doing a `System.Exit` in when the close button is hit? Do you get a stack trace?

Comment: the close button is on window. and I set: setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html):

> ```
>       EXIT_ON_CLOSE 
>       The exit application default window close operation.
> ```

In the `NewJFrame` class, remove this: `setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

This is making the whole application shutdown when the close button is hit!

Replace it by:
`setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

This way you are sure only the window is disposed, not the whole application

Comment: @PhiVH Please mark this as an answer if it fixed your issue :)

Comment: @PhiVH, if an answer solves your problem, you should click on the "check mark" to accept the answer -- that is how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @PhiVH What do you mean by ""check mark" thing" is that the X on the close button?

Comment: @PhiVH Ah I got yours too, you were talking about where to accept the answer right :D

Answer (score 1):

Can we guess that your Dialog has the "CLOSE_ON_EXIT" option set ot that it calls "System.exit()" directly?

If not, give more information.

Comment: Thank you, GETah answered my question and i solved my problem.